# Alias for "cd" which shows current directory each time I change directories?

Tags: alias, tcsh, pwd

In tcsh, I would like an alias to `pwd` after I `cd` to a different directory.

Previously I used the below alias for this, but it also changes the shell prompt to be `[current directory]>`. Due to project needs, I can't have the shell prompt changing any more, but I still want the current path to be shown each time I `cd`.

```
alias cd 'cd \!* ; set cwd=`pwd`;pwd;set prompt=$cwd:t\ \!\>\ '
```

I've tried messing with above alias to remove the `set prompt` but I have not gotten it to work (I don't understand the syntax).

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
alias cd 'cd \!*; set cwd=`pwd`; pwd'
```

This replaces `cd` with an alias which runs three commands:

```
cd \!*
```

which changes the directory,

```
set cwd=`pwd`
```

which stores the result of `pwd` in the `cwd` variable, and finally

```
pwd
```

which prints the current directory.

The second command is no longer useful since the prompt shouldn't need it, so you could simplify this to

```
alias cd 'cd \!*; pwd'
```

or better still,

```
alias cd 'cd -p \!*'
```

which uses the `-p` option to print the resulting directory.

(Note that in `tcsh`, you can specify `%/`or `%~` in the prompt to get the current working directory, instead of storing it in a variable. `%/` gives the full path in all cases, `%~` simplifies it using `~` when possible.)

Answer (score 2):

In `tcsh`, you can define the special `cwdcmd` *hook* alias that is invoked every time the current working directory changes:

```
alias cwdcmd pwd
```

`zsh` copied that concept (using a hook *function* instead of *alias* (`tcsh` has no function)):

```
chpwd() pwd
```

In anycase, if you want your prompt to have the trailing component of the current working directory, you don't need anything like that.

```
set prompt='%c !> '
```

would be enough. Also note that `tcsh` sets the `$cwd` variable by itself already, no need to set it by hand in a `cd` alias.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative might be using `rprompt`, this works exactly like the prompt, but on the *right* side:

e.g. with `set rprompt="%~"`:

```
% cd /usr/local/bin/                                       ~
% echo Hello                                               /usr/local/bin
Hello
%                                                          /usr/local/bin
```

You could also use your alias in this − anything that works for `prompt` should work for `rprompt`.

I don't know if this satisfies your "project needs" which prevent you from changing the regular prompt, but it could perhaps be an option.